# Padang Bai to Gili Trawangan by boat?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, indonesia, sea-travel, bali

I am in Indonesia and I want to go by boat from Padang Bai (Bali) to Gili Trawangan (Gili islands, Lombok).

What are my options available (ie. Public boat, shared fast boat, chartered fast boat, or else)?

Prices, duration of journey and schedules appreciated.

[image: Map for Padang Bai to Gili Trawangan journey]

[© OpenStreetMap contributors](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)

Answer (score 2):

The info below is from **2015**.

You can either take:

- Fast boat. It takes 1h30min. It costs circa 300'000 IDR. More on this further down.
- Public boat. It takes 4h. It costs 200'000 IDR.

---

For the fast boat, the price you get depends on the agency you contact, and the number of intermediaries between you and the actual company running the fast boat. Do get in touch (face to face or by phone) with many companies/agencies if you want the best price.

I paid 350'000 IDR the first time I took it. Another time I got a deal of 500'000 IDR for going and coming back!

---

Sanur express, +6281238028309 or +6281237043613, was the company who offered me the deal of 350'000 IDR, but this included a mini bus pick up from Kuta (or anywhere around, and also Ubud) to Padang Bai.

[image: Sanur express contact details]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very reliable websitte  http://www.rome2rio.com    My travel agent staff uses this site for point to point connections via Rail, Ferry ,Car, etc. It tells you the best mode of transport and how to reserve.
Go in Good Health, Eric

Comment: Rome2Rio also has bookmarkable URLs, so you should be able to give the OP a direct link for their journey and some advice!

Comment: @eric welcome to travel.stackexchange.com , I'm looking for accurate information (schedule, price, journey length, company details & so on). I really like rome2rio but it actually is not helping much for this topic as all the information is quite generic.